# Gnuplot offsets with custom range (v5.4)

Tags: gnuplot

I have a problem with how offsets work in gnuplot v5.4 compared to v5.2.
I tried to make the following graph (v5.2):

[image: example_5.2]

To create this graph, I used the following code...

```
set style line 1 lc rgb '#808080' lt 1 lw 2
set border 0 ls 1
set arrow from 0, graph 0 to 5, graph 0 nohead front ls 1
set arrow from graph 0,first 0 to graph 0, first 5 nohead front ls 1
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set lmargin 10
set bmargin 3.5
set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:5]
set offsets graph 0.1, graph 0.1, graph 0.1, graph 0.1
plot 'example.txt'
```

... and data.

```
#x  y
0   3.88222
1   4.20754
2   4.424
3   2.41443
4   1.95107
5   2.79098
```

In v5.4, this code results in a graph without offsets:

[image: example_5.4]

The documentation unfortunately does not address custom ranges.
I am not sure if this is a bug, a problem with my code or if the feature of using offsets and custom ranges got removed in gnuplot v5.4 altogether.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation section for "offset" is not good in gnuplot version 5.

My understanding is that the current (version 5.4) behavior is

- `offsets` only affect auto-scaling
- explicit axis ranges take precedence over auto-scaling, so offsets have no effect if there is an explicit range for that axis
- The style of plot shown in the query is best achieved in gnuplot 5.4 by using the keyword `rangelimited`, e.g. `set tics rangelimited` if you want this on all axes

The commands below work the same way in gnuplot versions 5.0 and 5.2 as they do in version 5.4, so I am thinking that this example shows not a sudden change between the two versions but rather a gradual accumulation of small differences between versions 4 and 5.  I will file a bug report pointing out the inadequacy of the current documentation section on "offset".

**Revised code**

```
# Modified for gnuplot version 5.4
set xtics rangelimited nomirror
set ytics rangelimited nomirror
set border 3
set offsets graph 0.1, graph 0.1, graph 0.1, graph 0.1
plot 'example.txt' with points
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A strange observation which I can reproduce. The following further minimized code behaves differently in gnuplot 5.2 and gnuplot 5.4

```
reset session
set xrange[0:5]
set yrange[0:5]
set offset graph 0.1, graph 0.1, graph 0.1, graph 0.1
plot x
```

I'm not sure why it is different. The following a bit cumbersome workaround will lead to the same result in gnuplot 5.2. and gnuplot 5.4 with the cost of replotting. But I hope there will be an easier solution which is currently not obvious to me. Maybe there is another setting in gnuplot 5.4 which "recovers" this 5.2 behaviour.

**Code:**

```
### "manual" offset for gnuplot 5.4
reset session

$Data <<EOD
#x  y
0   3.88222
1   4.20754
2   4.424
3   2.41443
4   1.95107
5   2.79098
EOD

set style line 1 lc rgb '#808080' lt 1 lw 2
set border 0 ls 1
set arrow from 0, graph 0 to 5, graph 0 nohead front ls 1
set arrow from graph 0,first 0 to graph 0, first 5 nohead front ls 1
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set lmargin 10
set bmargin 3.5

set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:5]

xRange(a)  = GPVAL_X_MAX  -GPVAL_X_MIN
yRange(a)  = GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN
xOffMin(a) = GPVAL_X_MIN - a*xRange(a)
xOffMax(a) = GPVAL_X_MAX + a*xRange(a)
yOffMin(a) = GPVAL_Y_MIN - a*yRange(a)
yOffMax(a) = GPVAL_Y_MAX + a*yRange(a)

plot $Data

set xrange [xOffMin(0.1):xOffMax(0.1)]   # graph 0.1 
set yrange [yOffMin(0.1):xOffMax(0.1)]   # graph 0.1 

replot
### end of code
```

**Result:** (gnuplot 5.2 and gnuplot 5.4)

[image]

**Addition:**

Well, you are setting a *fixed* x- and y-range and then you add 10% extra offset. So, you either could set directly `set xrange[-0.5:5.5]` and `set yrange[-0.5:5.5]` or do a calculation as in the code below. But, I agree if it worked as in gnuplot 5.2 where you set the ranges and then add 10% extra offset would be much more convenient.

```
reset session
xMin=0
xMax=5
yMin=0
yMax=5
OffLeft   = 0.1
OffRight  = 0.1
OffTop    = 0.1
OffBottom = 0.1
xRange = xMax-xMin
yRange = yMax-yMin

set xrange[xMin-OffLeft  *xRange : xMin+OffRight*xRange]
set yrange[xMin-OffBottom*yRange : yMin+OffTop  *yRange]

plot x
```